# How to display Excel file in a new tab using Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I am trying to display an Excel workbook in a browser (read only) using Javascript or Jquery. I've tried `"/help/TestXML.xls"`, `onClick="window.open('/help/TestXML.xls','_blank');"`, those two only get the workbook to download which isn't what I'm looking for, I need it to display the contents in a browser tab. An answer from this site using a Blob object only showed a blank tab. I know the solution will likely be IE only which is fine. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably can't do that.

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of, but I'm trying to see if anyone has had success before I call it quits.